# Printing a panel in c#

Tags: c#, printing, panel

Im printing a panel which is basically a registration form, and contain 3 small panels, but it print only a blank page... i tried many times but got no solution.

```
PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();
System.Drawing.Bitmap memoryImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel_stdadmcard.Width, panel_stdadmcard.Height);
panel_stdadmcard.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, panel_stdadmcard.ClientRectangle);
PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
if (myPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings values;
    values = myPrintDialog.PrinterSettings;
    myPrintDialog.Document = printDocument1;
    printDocument1.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    printDocument1.Print();
}
printDocument1.Dispose();
```

Comment: You appear to rely on PrintDocument's telepathic powers.  How does it know about your memoryImage variable?  Write an event handler for its PrintPage event.  The MSDN library article for PrintDocument does not omit that.

Answer (score 1):

You draw the panel to a bitmap, but you never use it, if this code is complete.
You should implement the PrintPage-Event of the printDocument. 
And there you should use DrawImage to Draw the image.

Answer (score 0):

Change `panel_stdadmcard.ClientRectangle` to `new Rectangle(0, 0, panel_stdadmcard.Width, panel_stdadmcard.Height)`